# Are questions about moviegoing culture on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Would a question about American movie audiences' habit of leaving a movie theater immediately when the closing credits start, and how that compares with the rest of the world, be considered on-topic?

Comment: Shame this is *probably* not on topic - I'd be interested in knowing more about this. Having lived in the UK & USA where this is the norm, I'm curious to know where they don't do this.

Comment: @iandotkelly A French teacher in high school told us that in either France or Europe in general they sit through the closing credits before leaving the theater.

Answer (score 1):

It's a potentially interesting question BUT I don't really think it fits the M&TV.SE model which is more about appreciation of Movies and TV themselves rather than how people act in a movie theater.

Your question is about human behaviour or perhaps [psychology](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/) so perhaps another site on the network might be better but make sure you check that site's guidelines first.